# In what file Systemd-hibernate service dumps the RAM content?

Tags: systemd, hibernate

I'd wanted to get it from a disk image to analyze with Volatility but I've not been able to find it (I've searched in systemd-sleep.conf file but there's no related directive)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here (https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html) or here (https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Use+a+swap+file+and+enable+hibernation+on+Arch+Linux+-+including+on+a+LUKS+root+partition ...it doesn't uses Systemd-hibernate but it's interesting though) are available some rellevant responses to this question

Reference doc is here (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/swsusp-and-swap-files.txt)

Thanks

Comment: Link-only answers are low quality. A link will be useless if the linked resource disappears or moves. Therefore you should quote the relevant fragments here, so the answer is standalone and directly answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for your time spent on doing the research, if you could summarize what you have found it would help us all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

**1.-** Create swap file on root partition (it's worth noting that you'll want to have a swap file at least as large as the computer's RAM)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=17408
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

**2.-** Activate swap persistently

```
echo "/swapfile none    swap    defaults 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount -a
```

**3.-** Find out the UUID of the partition on which the swap file resides. We'll need this in later steps

```
findmnt -no UUID -T /swapfile
```

**4.-** Find out the swap file offset. We'll need this in later steps, too.

```
sudo filefrag -v /swapfile
```

> NOTE: From this command's output, the first block of numbers from the
> "physical_offset" column is the value you need (only copy the numbers,
> and not the dots that follow the number block)

**5.-** Edit the **/etc/default/grub** file in order to boot with the "resume" and "resume offset" kernel parameters. In this file, at the end of the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line, before the ending ", add the following: `resume=UUID=UUID_FROM_STEP_3 resume_offset=SWAP_OFFSET_FROM_STEP_4` (replace the values with the UUID you've got under step 3 and the swap resume offset you've got under step 4) For example, this is how the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line would look after adding the swap UUID and swap offset: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=4a59c6a7-ca54-4e24-a362-3eac83bfe226 resume_offset=4974592"

**5BIS.-**..and update the GRUB configuration. To do it on Debian-based Linux distributions, all you have to do is run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

**6.-** Create (or edit if already exists) **/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume** with the swap UUID and resume offset (this is only on Debian-based Linux distribution...in RedHat's ones you should use Dracut). In this file, if you have a line beginning with "RESUME", edit that line, or if there's no such line (or the file is completely empty), add the line so that it looks like this: `RESUME=UUID=UUID_FROM_STEP_3 resume_offset=SWAP_OFFSET_FROM_STEP_4`

**6BIS.-** ...and regenerate initramfs using this command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

**7.-** Reboot your computer. After rebooting, hibernate your computer using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```